# shell script array range data from a variable

Tags: linux, shell

I am trying to expand server names in a host file, which is following format

```
#hostfile
server0[1-2]1
server1[2-3]4
#end
```

I manually changed a entry in hostfile i.e server0[1-2]1 to (server0{1..2}1) and tried the following in bash shell and I was able to expand the variable:

```
my_array=(server0{1..2}1)
printf '%s\n' "${my_array[@]}"

Output:
server011
server021
```

but when I try to do the same through a script it not printing output in above for mat here as it just prints the following:

```
server0{1..2}1
server1{2..3}4
```

Is it a problem in variable to array conversion?

script:
    #!/bin/bash
    grep -Ev '#|^$' hostfile | while read line; 
    do 
    my_array=()
    if [ `echo $line|grep -c 'host1'` -eq 1 ]; 
        then 
        echo $line >> new_hostfile
    elif [ `echo $line|grep -c '^s'` -eq 1 ]
        then 
        m=`echo $line|sed -e 's/:/../g' -e 's/\[/{/g' -e 's/\]/}/g'`
        my_array="($m)"
        printf '%s\n' "${my_array[@]}" >> new_hostfile
    fi; 
    done

The output desired from the script is

```
server011
server021
server124
server134
```

Comment: Are you running the script with `/bin/sh` instead of `/bin/bash`? POSIX sh doesn't know about brace expansion.

Comment: No I'm running my script with /bin/bash

Comment: I can't reproduce this. If I put your code into a script and run it, brace expansion works without problems. It is possible to compile Bash without brace expansion, but since you're saying it works for you interactively, I still strongly suspect that you're running the script under a different shell than what you use interactively. What shebang line do you use, and how do you run the script?